# knockout.js - hasFocus not working

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to implement simple demo code which uses 'hasFocus' binding.  Sample code is available [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html)  It is also working fine in the browser (IE)

When I copy same code and paste it in my MVC application it stops working.  Even if after clicking on button its not setting focus on text box.  Below is my code:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input data-bind="hasFocus: isSelected" />
        <button data-bind="click: setIsSelected">Focus programmatically</button>
        <span data-bind="visible: isSelected">The textbox has focus</span>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js")"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
           var viewModel =
                {
                    isSelected: ko.observable(false),
                    setIsSelected: function () { this.isSelected(true) }
                };
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
    </script>
}
```

Does anyone know what has went wrong here?

Comment: Is the script section included in the output? Please check the html source of the rendered page. It is possible that you are not rendering that section anywhere. Use [`@Html.RenderSection()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537886%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) somewhere in your layout.

Comment: I just tried it in my MVC app, it works fine with all browsers. as a side note, why don't you use Bundles? instead of direct link to scripts?

Comment: Thanks @avrahamcool.  Actually this is bug in older version of ko.  I downloaded latest version of knockoutjs using packagemanager and its fixed in it. ( knockoutjs3.0.0 )

Comment: you are right, I had the latest release of KO in my project.. +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is bug in the knockout framework and its fixed in knockoutjs3.0.0.  You can donwload latest knockout library using [nuget package manager](http://www.nuget.org/packages/knockoutjs)